# Laurent Expansion of Function Defined as Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Let $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus [0,1] $ and define $f(z) = \int^{1}_{0} \frac{x}{x-z} dx$. Find the Laurent Expansion of $f(z)$ in the annulus $A= [{z: |z|>1}]$, and determine its region of convergence and state the explicit form for $f(z)$.

Any hints would help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the expansion
$$ \frac{x}{x-z} = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{z}\right)^n $$
valid for $|x|<|z|$
and then integrate term by term...

Comment: Did you get this series by writing $\frac{x}{x-z} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{x}}$ and using Geometric Series?

Comment: @James.Welch: yes, that is correct

Comment: Since it is written in the way $\frac{x}{x-z} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z}{x}}$ wouldn't the sum be $\frac{x}{x-z} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (\frac{z}{x})^n$

Comment: @James.Welch No, that semis would be valid in the wrong annulus ($|x|>|z|$). You should write $\frac{x}{x-z} = -\frac{x}{z} \frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{z}}$ and then use the geometric series.

Comment: I see now, thanks for the response